# How create quotes when using paste with collapse in R

Tags: r

I have dataframe `df`, and want a row with collapsed column values with quotes. Output should be `"'a','b','c'"`, but I have `"a,b,c"`. How can I get the right output?

```
df<-data.frame(
  a=c("a","b","c"),
  number=c(1,2,3)
)
paste(df$a,collapse = ",")
```

Comment: `paste(sQuote(df$a),collapse=",")` or `paste(paste0("'",df$a,"'"),collapse=",")`, though the latter will not properly "escape" embedded single quotes.

Comment: Do you need this output for an SQL query? Because `dbplyr` could easily solve this issue for you then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
paste(
    "'",c("A", "B", "C"), "'", sep = "", collapse = ","
)
```

It gives the following output,

```
"'A','B','C'"
```

Comment: thank you, but If I need to place "\' " instead of simply "'", what should I do? i tried paste("\'"...) however got only ', tried paste("\\'"...) and got "\\'), Output should be like " \'A,\',\'B\',\'C\' "